# Persisting Page on Kendo Grid with AngularJS When Navigating Back

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo Grid with AngularJS.
When going into a details page and then hitting the back button it resets to the first page. I would like to persist the page when going back to the grid.

Here's the JS code:

```
pageable: { pageSizes: [20, 50, 100, 500]

         },
        info: true,

        dataSource: {
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: "total"
            },
            transport: {
                read: getItems
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 20,

            aggregate: [
              { field: "Total", aggregate: "Sum" },
              { field: "Outstanding", aggregate: "Sum" }
            ]
        }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="grid" kendo-grid="vm.grid" k-options="vm.gridOptions">
    </div>
```